# What should I be returning in a getter method in swift

Tags: swift, swift3

```
var userState: UserState {
    get {
        return userState
    }
    set {
        print("\(self.userState)")
    }
}
```

Returning userState causes an infinite loop. I'm not interested in the getter method and just want to return the value of the property in the getter. I would rather like to customise the setter method.

Comment: The answer depends on what you plan to do in the setter. Show your actual setter.

Comment: What is it you are intending to accomplish?

Comment: If you absolutely need to override `set` and `get`, keep `userState` public and create a private store `_userState` which the getter and setter read from.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you would like to override a setter, but keep your property readable, then you need to make a variable to "back" the property:

```
private var storedUserState: UserState
var userState: UserState {
    get {
        return storedUserState
    }
    set {
        print("Before: \(self.storedUserState)")
        storedUserState = newValue
        print("After: \(self.storedUserState)")
    }
}
```

If you would like to customize a setter method, but would prefer the property to remain *stored*, use property observers instead of overriding the accessors:

```
var userState: UserState = nil {
    willSet(newState) {
        print("About to set userState: \(newState)")
    }
    didSet {
        print("Finished: new=\(userState), old=\(oldValue)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Ohh boy, this contrast is sooo great. I was always confused about these two. @others: the first way is also known as **computed** property

Comment: @Honey I mean, let others use expressions like `if (obj.userState.someField > someValue)`, i.e. providing a getter that returns something useful. Another alternative is to let property getter throw an exception, creating an effectively "write-only" property (not a very good idea; one should go with a method at that point).

Comment: "property getter throw an exception, creating an effectively "write-only" property" you mean the `get` would look like: `get { fatalError()}` really don't understand where that could be used

Comment: @Honey Yes, something like this: `user.password = "12345"` instead of `user.setPassword("12345")` You don't want an ability to write `"password: \(user.password)"`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `set`, what you want is `willSet` or `didSet`, which get run before/after the value changes. Then you can omit `get`.

With `willSet`, since the variable hasn't changed yet, the new value is available in a parameter called `newValue`. Conversely, `didSet` has `oldValue`.